# Type-preserving rounding in Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point, rounding, built-in

Is there a *built-in* function in Haskell that rounds a real floating-point number to the nearest whole number, without changing the type of said number?

```hs
sameTypeRound f == fromIntegral (round f)
```

Comment: You can try searching [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for `RealFrac a => a -> a`. I could find nothing, though

Comment: @A.Yurchenko Yeah, that's what I did before asking this question. Like you, I came up empty-handed.

Comment: What is wrong with defining `sameTypeRound f = fromIntegral (round f)`?

Comment: @user2407038 Nothing really. I'll probably settle for that definition, albeit with a different name. I'm just curious though, because most languages I'm familiar with don't have type-changing `round`, `ceiling` and `floor` functions. Although admittedly, it makes sense for those functions to return an integer type, especially given the nature of Haskell.

Comment: "it makes sense for those functions to return an integer type, especially given the nature of Haskell" - indeed, the strength of the Haskell type system makes it easy to model the true type of `round`, which is `Real -> Integer`. If we had `round' :: Real -> Real` then recovering `round` from this function would be somewhat difficult. But as you've seen, the other direction is very easy. Furthermore, the standard lib. doesn't typically define `h = f . g` if `f` and `g` are already library functions; if it did, the syntactic noise would be simply intractable.

Comment: @user2407038 I'm not baffled by the fact that it's not defined in `base` or `Prelude`, merely curious. I take your point about function compositions, although the upshot of that is that you end up redefining *very* common operations yourself, or depending on a metric tonne of fairly small libraries. Not a major concern, but I suppose it irks me slightly in spite of that.

Comment: @user2407038 If you write up a short answer stating that such a function *does not exist* in the Prelude and explain why (as you already have in the comments), I'll happily accept it.

Comment: If you do define `sameTypeRound` I would use `fromInteger . round` instead of `fromIntegral . round`. It fixes the ambiguous type without a type signature and `fromIntegral` is just `fromInteger . toInteger` anyway.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why `round` was not given the type `round :: (RealFrac a, Num b) => a -> b`. Then you could literally just use `round`; and none of the methods that `Integral` has but `Num` doesn't seem particularly useful for implementing `round`. This might be worth a separate question.

Comment: @DanielWagner `properFraction` returns an `(Integral, Real)`

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake That just pushes the question one layer deeper: why isn't *that* one a `(Num a, Real b) => (a, b)`?

Comment: @DanielWagner Probably because the first value *has* to be a whole number, and the type ensures that. Haskellers are pretty fond of encoding properties via types. That being said, I obviously agree with you that the type you suggest would be *useful* (it's why I asked the question, after all).

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Values of type `forall a. Num a => a` are *also* guaranteed to be whole numbers: by parametricity, they can only be constructed by applications of the `Num` methods, which all look like they preserve whole-ness to me.

Comment: `abs` doesn't preserve whole-ness for certain types (and type classes can't enforce rules beyond types). There's also the matter of `Num` being the class for *all numbers* (conceptually). Again, if I had to hazard a guess as to what the motivation was, I'd say it's about what the types signify. I wouldn't be the first to say that the numerical hierarchy is broken in some ways though.